# How can i destroy all the objects before creating new ones?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i want to do is that only if i change the number of objects to create in the inspector then first destroy all the existing objects if there are any and then create the new number of objects.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class InstantiateObjects : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject prefab;
        public Terrain terrain;
        public float yOffset = 0.5f;
        public int objectsToInstantiate;
        public bool parent = true;

        private float terrainWidth;
        private float terrainLength;
        private float xTerrainPos;
        private float zTerrainPos;
        private int numberOfObjectsToCreate;
        private GameObject objInstance;

        public void Start()
        {
            //Get terrain size
            terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
            terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

            //Get terrain position
            xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
            zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

            numberOfObjectsToCreate = objectsToInstantiate;
            generateObjectOnTerrain();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (numberOfObjectsToCreate != objectsToInstantiate)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < objectsToInstantiate; i++)
                {
                    Destroy(objInstance);
                }
                    generateObjectOnTerrain();
            }

        }

        public void generateObjectOnTerrain()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToInstantiate; i++)
            {
                //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
                float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
                float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);
                float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

                //Apply Offset if needed
                yVal = yVal + yOffset;

                //Generate the Prefab on the generated position        
                objInstance = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);
                objInstance.name = "Teleportation Booth";
                if (parent)
                    objInstance.transform.parent = this.transform;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the variable in the Inspector to set the number of objects to create:

```
public int objectsToInstantiate;
```

This variable should be helper to check if there was any changes if a new number of objects to create was changed in the inspector:

```
private int numberOfObjectsToCreate;
```

And the code in the Update function but it does nothing. When i type new value in the inspector it's not changing anything.

Comment: You should never use Instantiate to create objects, that could be replaced by the previous one, at first create pool controller, that will have pre-defined quantity of objects, and if will be needed more it will create but if not, it will only change properties of unused object, using this you will get rid of memory leak(in this problem)

Comment: @ArtemLayko i forgot to mention that i want to clone existing gameobject that's why i'm using Instantiate. But if i want to clone and/or create new objects how should i do it then ?

Comment: use an object pool

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change `Destroy(objInstance);` to `DestroyImmediately(objInstance);` should work.

However, to remove and add new objects in `update` is not a good idea. you may try to maintain a object pool to add/remove a specific object, and only when many objects are removing/adding in one action, you should do the batch process.